# How to write custom insert Query Spring Webflux, and return custom response class?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactive

I am new to Reactive programming and I got stuck writing a custom Insert query.

So far I have a FriendshipRepository.java class.

```
public interface FriendshipRepository extends R2dbcRepository<Friendship, String> {

    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO public.friendship(requester_id, addressee_id) values (:requesterid::uuid, :addresseeid::uuid)")
    public Mono<Void> insertFriendRequest(
            @Param("requesterid") String requesterId,
            @Param("addresseeid") String addresseeId
    );
 }
```

And a FriendshipController.java class.

```
@RestController
public class FriendsController {

    private final FriendshipRepository friendshipRepository;

    public FriendsController(FriendshipRepository friendshipRepository) {
        this.friendshipRepository = friendshipRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/request", produces = "application/json")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<RequestResponse>> sendFriendRequest(@RequestBody FriendRequest friendRequest, @AuthenticationPrincipal Mono<User> principal) throws Exception {

        String id = principal.map(User::getId).toFuture().get();

        return friendshipRepository.insertFriendRequest(id, friendRequest.getUserId()).log()
                .then(Mono.just("NEXT"))
                .map(e -> {
                    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(new RequestResponse("Success", ResponseCode.SUCCESS));
                }).onErrorResume(e -> {
                    return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body(new RequestResponse("Friend request was unsuccessful ", ResponseCode.REFUSED)));
                });

    }
}
```

This is a working example. 
But I dont understand why I have to call `.then(Mono.just("NEXT"))` and create a new Mono to be able to return a custom `ResponseEntity<RequestResponse>>`. I also tried merge the the whole process. I meen by this at the begining when I get the Id from the `ReactiveSpringSecutiryContext` that is a blocking line of code and If I know it correctly that is a bad approach in Reactive programming.

I tried this approach but in this case, I can only retrun the Id of the user.

```
    Mono<String> userId = principal.map(User::getId);

    return userId.doOnNext(id -> {
        friendshipRepository.insertFriendRequest(id, friendRequest.getUserId()).log()
                .map(e -> {
                    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(new RequestResponse("SIKER", ResponseCode.SUCCESS));
                })
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                    return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body(new RequestResponse("Friend request was unsuccessful ", ResponseCode.REFUSED)));
                }).subscribe();
//                    .doOnSuccess(e ->  ServerResponse.noContent().build((new RequestResponse("SIKER", ResponseCode.SUCCESS)), Void.class));
    });
```

How could I rewrite this endpoint? Or does my whole approach inaproptirate? 
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Because you are calling `map` on a function that returns a `Mono<Void>`. Think about it, you cant map something that returns void. What would you map? So now when you are returning something (a Mono<String> since you are calling Mono.just) then suddenly the map function has something to map over in that case string

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and yes it is completely logical. I have tried it and it was working with `RETURNING id`. But I am still wondering whether is it possible to write it widthout RETURNING value, or in a more elegant way, and why I cannot return from the `doOnSuccess` clause.

Comment: `doOnSuccess` is used for handling side effects. For instance logging or doing something that you dont wish to know the result of. Thats why you cannot return anything new from it

Comment: You can probably use `switchIfEmpty` operator to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks it is quite clear now. The last think I don't like about my solution is the blocking line of code, where I get the Id from the 'ReactiveSecurityContext'.  Is it an appropriate solution, or should I rewrite it somehow?

Comment: You can use the `then` or `thenReturn` operator instead of `subscribe` and `doOnSuccess`. I suggest you go through all operators so you get a basic understanding of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the nicest solution, but better then it was.

My query:

```
public interface FriendshipRepository extends R2dbcRepository<Friendship, String> {

   @Query(value = "INSERT INTO public.friendship(requester_id, addressee_id) values (:requesterid::uuid, :addresseeid::uuid) RETURNING id")
   public Mono<String> insertFriendRequest(
        @Param("requesterid") String requesterId,
        @Param("addresseeid") String addresseeId
   );
}
```

My api:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/request", produces = "application/json")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<RequestResponse>> sendFriendRequest(@RequestBody FriendRequest friendRequest, @AuthenticationPrincipal Mono<User> principal) throws Exception {

    String id = principal.map(User::getId).toFuture().get();

    return friendshipRepository.insertFriendRequest(id, friendRequest.getUserId()).log()
        .map(e -> {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(new RequestResponse("Success", ResponseCode.SUCCESS));
        }).onErrorResume(e -> {
            return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body(new RequestResponse("Friend request was unsuccessful ", ResponseCode.REFUSED)));
        });
}
```